# Nginx doesn't serve file when cors configured

Tags: nginx, cors

I host an angular application on a nginx server. I need to configure cors as well, because I need ressources from a different domain. But when I configure my cors policy as shown below, my nginx server doesn't serve files as it should.

Can anyone tell me where my problem relates in?
Thank you very much!

```
location / {
                        #if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                                #
                                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                                #
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                                #
                                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                                #
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                                #add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                                #add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                                #return 204;
                        #}
                        #if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                        #}
                        #if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                                #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
                        #}
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
                }
```

(I commented the configuration out, because I needed the server to work as it should.)

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: When I try to access the servers with a specific path, lets say: https://example.com/test it doesn't work with the cors configuration. When the cors configuration is disabled like in the code above it's working. And I don't know why :(

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I get an 404 error in my browser. I'm sry for the pure documentation...

Comment: [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) and `try_files` will be ignored, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548301/if-conditions-break-try-files-in-nginx-configuration